# Is it possible to turn quartely data to monthly?

Tags: pandas

I'm struggling with this problem and I'm not sure if I'm approaching it correctly.
I have this dataset:

```
        ticker  date    filing_date_x   currency_symbol_x   researchdevelopment effectofaccountingcharges   incomebeforetax minorityinterest    netincome   sellinggeneraladministrative    grossprofit ebit    nonoperatingincomenetother  operatingincome otheroperatingexpenses  interestexpense taxprovision    interestincome  netinterestincome   extraordinaryitems  nonrecurring    otheritems  incometaxexpense    totalrevenue    totaloperatingexpenses  costofrevenue   totalotherincomeexpensenet  discontinuedoperations  netincomefromcontinuingops  netincomeapplicabletocommonshares   preferredstockandotheradjustments   filing_date_y   currency_symbol_y   totalassets intangibleassets    earningassets   othercurrentassets  totalliab   totalstockholderequity  deferredlongtermliab    ... totalcurrentliabilities shorttermdebt   shortlongtermdebt   shortlongtermdebttotal  otherstockholderequity  propertyplantequipment  totalcurrentassets  longterminvestments nettangibleassets   shortterminvestments    netreceivables  longtermdebt    inventory   accountspayable totalpermanentequity    noncontrollinginterestinconsolidatedentity  temporaryequityredeemablenoncontrollinginterests    accumulatedothercomprehensiveincome additionalpaidincapital commonstocktotalequity  preferredstocktotalequity   retainedearningstotalequity treasurystock   accumulatedamortization noncurrrentassetsother  deferredlongtermassetcharges    noncurrentassetstotal   capitalleaseobligations longtermdebttotal   noncurrentliabilitiesother  noncurrentliabilitiestotal  negativegoodwill    warrants    preferredstockredeemable    capitalsurpluse liabilitiesandstockholdersequity    cashandshortterminvestments propertyplantandequipmentgross  accumulateddepreciation commonstocksharesoutstanding

116638  JNJ.US  2019-12-31  2020-02-18  USD 3.232000e+09    NaN 4.218000e+09    NaN 4.010000e+09    6.039000e+09    1.363200e+10    6.119000e+09    6.500000e+07    4.238000e+09    NaN 85000000.0  208000000.0 81000000.0  -4000000.0  NaN 104000000.0 NaN 208000000.0 2.074700e+10    9.414000e+09    7.115000e+09    -1.200000e+08   NaN 4.010000e+09    4.010000e+09    NaN 2020-02-18  USD 1.577280e+11    4.764300e+10    NaN 2.486000e+09    9.825700e+10    5.947100e+10    5.958000e+09    ... 3.596400e+10    1.202000e+09    1.202000e+09    NaN -1.589100e+10   1.765800e+10    4.527400e+10    1.149000e+09    -2.181100e+10   1.982000e+09    1.448100e+10    2.649400e+10    9.020000e+09    3.476200e+10    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 3.120000e+09    NaN 1.106590e+11    -3.841700e+10   NaN 5.695000e+09    7.819000e+09    1.124540e+11    NaN 2.649400e+10    2.984100e+10    6.229300e+10    NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.577280e+11    1.928700e+10    NaN NaN 2.632507e+09
116569  JNJ.US  2020-03-31  2020-04-29  USD 2.580000e+09    NaN 6.509000e+09    NaN 5.796000e+09    5.203000e+09    1.364400e+10    8.581000e+09    7.460000e+08    5.788000e+09    NaN 25000000.0  713000000.0 67000000.0  42000000.0  300000000.0 58000000.0  NaN 713000000.0 2.069100e+10    7.135000e+09    7.047000e+09    6.210000e+08    NaN 5.796000e+09    5.796000e+09    NaN 2020-04-29  USD 1.550170e+11    4.733800e+10    NaN 2.460000e+09    9.372300e+10    6.129400e+10    5.766000e+09    ... 3.368900e+10    2.190000e+09    2.190000e+09    NaN -1.624300e+10   1.740100e+10    4.422600e+10    NaN -1.951500e+10   2.494000e+09    1.487400e+10    2.539300e+10    8.868000e+09    3.149900e+10    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 3.120000e+09    NaN 1.129010e+11    -3.848400e+10   NaN 5.042000e+09    NaN 7.539000e+09    NaN 2.539300e+10    2.887500e+10    6.003400e+10    NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.550170e+11    1.802400e+10    4.324700e+10    -2.584600e+10   2.632392e+09
116420  JNJ.US  2020-06-30  2020-07-24  USD 2.707000e+09    NaN 3.940000e+09    NaN 3.626000e+09    4.993000e+09    1.177900e+10    5.711000e+09    -5.000000e+06   3.990000e+09    NaN 45000000.0  314000000.0 19000000.0  -26000000.0 NaN 67000000.0  NaN 314000000.0 1.833600e+10    7.839000e+09    6.557000e+09    -8.500000e+07   NaN 3.626000e+09    3.626000e+09    NaN 2020-07-24  USD 1.583800e+11    4.741300e+10    NaN 2.688000e+09    9.540200e+10    6.297800e+10    5.532000e+09    ... 3.677200e+10    5.332000e+09    5.332000e+09    NaN -1.553300e+10   1.759800e+10    4.589200e+10    NaN -1.832500e+10   7.961000e+09    1.464500e+10    2.506200e+10    9.424000e+09    3.144000e+10    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 3.120000e+09    NaN 1.138980e+11    -3.850700e+10   NaN 5.782000e+09    NaN 7.805000e+09    NaN 2.506200e+10    2.803600e+10    5.863000e+10    NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.583800e+11    1.913500e+10    4.405600e+10    -2.645800e+10   2.632377e+09
116235  JNJ.US  2020-09-30  2020-10-23  USD 2.840000e+09    NaN 4.401000e+09    NaN 3.554000e+09    5.431000e+09    1.411000e+10    4.445000e+09    -1.188000e+09   5.633000e+09    NaN 44000000.0  847000000.0 12000000.0  -32000000.0 NaN 206000000.0 NaN 847000000.0 2.108200e+10    8.477000e+09    6.972000e+09    -1.268000e+09   NaN 3.554000e+09    3.554000e+09    NaN 2020-10-23  USD 1.706930e+11    4.700600e+10    NaN 2.619000e+09    1.062200e+11    6.447300e+10    5.615000e+09    ... 3.884700e+10    5.078000e+09    5.078000e+09    NaN -1.493800e+10   1.785500e+10    5.757800e+10    NaN -1.684000e+10   1.181600e+10    1.457900e+10    3.268000e+10    9.599000e+09    3.376900e+10    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 3.120000e+09    NaN 1.148310e+11    -3.854000e+10   NaN 6.131000e+09    NaN 7.816000e+09    NaN 3.268000e+10    2.907800e+10    6.737300e+10    NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.706930e+11    3.078100e+10    4.516200e+10    -2.730700e+10   2.632167e+09
116135  JNJ.US  2020-12-31  2021-02-22  USD 4.032000e+09    NaN 1.647000e+09    NaN 1.738000e+09    6.457000e+09    1.466100e+10    1.734000e+09    -2.341000e+09   4.075000e+09    NaN 87000000.0  -91000000.0 13000000.0  -74000000.0 NaN 97000000.0  NaN -91000000.0 2.247500e+10    1.058600e+10    7.814000e+09    -2.414000e+09   NaN 1.738000e+09    1.738000e+09    NaN 2021-02-22  USD 1.748940e+11    5.340200e+10    NaN 3.132000e+09    1.116160e+11    6.327800e+10    7.214000e+09    ... 4.249300e+10    2.631000e+09    2.631000e+09    NaN -1.524200e+10   1.876600e+10    5.123700e+10    NaN -2.651700e+10   1.120000e+10    1.357600e+10    3.263500e+10    9.344000e+09    3.986200e+10    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 3.120000e+09    NaN 1.138900e+11    -3.849000e+10   NaN 6.562000e+09    NaN 8.534000e+09    NaN 3.263500e+10    2.927400e+10    6.912300e+10    NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.748940e+11    2.518500e+10    NaN NaN 2.632512e+09
```

then I have this dataframe(daily) prices:

```
    ticker  date    open    high    low close   adjusted_close  volume
0   JNJ.US  2021-08-02  172.470 172.840 171.300 172.270 172.2700    3620659
1   JNJ.US  2021-07-30  172.540 172.980 171.840 172.200 172.2000    5346400
2   JNJ.US  2021-07-29  172.740 173.340 171.090 172.180 172.1800    4214100
3   JNJ.US  2021-07-28  172.730 173.380 172.080 172.180 172.1800    5750700
4   JNJ.US  2021-07-27  171.800 172.720 170.670 172.660 172.6600    7089300
```

I have daily data in the price data but I have quarterly data in the first data frame. I want to merge the dataframe in a way that all the prices between Jan-01-2020 and Mar-01-2020 are being merged with the correct row.

I'm not sure exactly how to do this. I thought of extracting the date to month-year but I still don't know how to merge based on the range of values?

Any suggestions would be welcomed, if I'm not clear please let me know and I can clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you could create common *year* and *quarter* columns for each DataFrame and do a merge on those columns. I did a left merge if you only want to match columns in the left dataset (daily data).

If this is not what you are looking for, could you please clarify with a sample input/output?

```
# importing pandas as pd
import pandas as pd
  
# Creating dummy data of daily values
dt = pd.Series(['2020-08-02', '2020-07-30', '2020-07-29',
                '2020-07-28', '2020-07-27'])

# Convert the underlying data to datetime 
dt = pd.to_datetime(dt)

dt_df = pd.DataFrame(dt, columns=['date'])

dt_df['quarter_1'] = dt_df['date'].dt.quarter
dt_df['year_1'] = dt_df['date'].dt.year

print(dt_df)
```

---

```
        date  quarter_1  year_1
0 2020-08-02          3    2020
1 2020-07-30          3    2020
2 2020-07-29          3    2020
3 2020-07-28          3    2020
4 2020-07-27          3    2020
```

---

```
# Creating dummy data of quarterly values
dt2 = pd.Series(['2019-12-31', '2020-03-31', '2020-06-30',
                '2020-09-30', '2020-12-31'])

# Convert the underlying data to datetime 
dt2 = pd.to_datetime(dt2)

dt2_df = pd.DataFrame(sr2, columns=['date2'])


dt2_df['quarter_2'] = dt2_df['date2'].dt.quarter
dt2_df['year_2'] = dt2_df['date2'].dt.year

print(dt2_df)
```

---

```
  date_quarter  quarter_2  year_2
0   2019-12-31          4    2019
1   2020-03-31          1    2020
2   2020-06-30          2    2020
3   2020-09-30          3    2020
4   2020-12-31          4    2020
```

Then you can just merge on how ever you want.

```
dt_df.merge(dt2_df, how='left', left_on=['quarter_1', 'year_1'], right_on=['quarter_2', 'year_2'] , validate="many_to_many")
```

---

**OUTPUT:**

```
        date  quarter_1  year_1 date_quarter  quarter_2  year_2
0 2020-08-02          3    2020   2020-09-30          3    2020
1 2020-07-30          3    2020   2020-09-30          3    2020
2 2020-07-29          3    2020   2020-09-30          3    2020
3 2020-07-28          3    2020   2020-09-30          3    2020
4 2020-07-27          3    2020   2020-09-30          3    2020
```